# Update a single row using Entity Framework - when using entity mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to update a single value in the database using Entity Framework code-first.

It's throwing the following error:

> Attaching an entity of type
>   'WarehouseAPI.Core.DataEntities.Models.TaskDetail' failed because
>   another entity of the same type already has the same primary key
>   value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the
>   state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the
>   graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities
>   are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In
>   this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track
>   the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or
>   'Modified' as appropriate.

```
[Table("tblTaskDetail")]
public partial class tblTaskDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskDetailID { get; set; }

    public int? ScheduleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string RobotID { get; set; }

    public Guid? SessionID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string TaskStatus { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime? TaskScheduledOn { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string TaskSummary { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime? TaskStartedOnUtc { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime? TaskCompletedOnUtc { get; set; }
}

public class TaskDetail
{
    public int TaskDetailID { get; set; }
    public int? ScheduleId { get; set; }
    public string RobotID { get; set; }
    public Guid? SessionID { get; set; }
    public string TaskStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime TaskScheduledOn { get; set; }
    public string TaskSummary { get; set; }
    public DateTime TaskStartedOnUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime TaskCompletedOnUtc { get; set; }
}

public class TaskDetailMapper:EntityTypeConfiguration<TaskDetail>
{
    public TaskDetailMapper()
    {
        this.ToTable("tblTaskDetail");
        this.HasKey(hk => hk.TaskDetailID);
        this.Property(o => o.RobotID).HasColumnName("RobotID");
        this.Property(o => o.ScheduleId).HasColumnName("ScheduleId");
        this.Property(o => o.SessionID).HasColumnName("SessionID");
        this.Property(o => o.TaskCompletedOnUtc).HasColumnName("TaskCompletedOnUtc");
        this.Property(o => o.TaskDetailID).HasColumnName("TaskDetailID");
        this.Property(o => o.TaskScheduledOn).HasColumnName("TaskScheduledOn");
        this.Property(o => o.TaskStartedOnUtc).HasColumnName("TaskStartedOnUtc");
        this.Property(o => o.TaskStatus).HasColumnName("TaskStatus");
        this.Property(o => o.TaskSummary).HasColumnName("TaskSummary");
    }
}

public partial class WarehouseAPIContext : DbContext
{
    public WarehouseAPIContext() : base("name=WarehouseAPIContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TaskDetailMapper());
    }
}

public class TaskDetailRepository:APIRepository<TaskDetail>
{
    WarehouseAPIContext _context;

    public TaskDetailRepository(WarehouseAPIContext context):base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public TaskDetail UpdateTaskStartingTime(TaskDetail entity)
    {
        try
        {
            var taskDetail = new TaskDetail() { TaskStartedOnUtc = entity.TaskStartedOnUtc, TaskStatus = entity.TaskStatus,SessionID = entity.SessionID, TaskDetailID = entity.TaskDetailID };

             dbSet.Attach(taskDetail);    // THROWS THE ERROR
            _context.Entry(taskDetail).Property(x => x.TaskStartedOnUtc).IsModified = true;
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

public class APIRepository<T> where T:class
{
        internal WarehouseAPIContext wContext;
        internal DbSet<T> dbSet;

        public APIRepository(WarehouseAPIContext context)
        {
            wContext = context;
            dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        }

        public virtual T Update(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                var entry = wContext.Entry(entity);
                dbSet.Attach(entity);
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                wContext.SaveChanges();
                return entity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ExceptionHandler.Handle(ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is that entity already available in the context cache? Are you loading that entity from database in some other place in the same context? Also why two context objects - `dbSet` and `_context`. I think, when you use `.Entry`, you can skip the `.Attach` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways to do this, either first load the entity you want to update copy the changes to this entity and save changes, which I prefer, the second option is to  load the entity you want to update, then de attach it, and attach it back , finally save the context changes.

you cannot attach an already attached  entity, EF will insert the object again